# Not able to add user into Domain Admins Group on EC2 AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, group-policy

I have several EC2 created on AWS they are all in the same domain.  I want to use group policy to share a local drive across all domain computers so any computer in the domain can access that drive.

I have problem when adding my domain account into the "Domain Admins" group.
When I do that I got an error:"you do not have permission to modify the group".  Some people saying this is a Windows Server 2008 r2 bug. 
I have to add my account into this group, because only the user in this group have permission to link and Group Policy Object, so that it will work.

It seems that AWS prevent any modification to some user groups.
It also not allow me to add a user into the Delegation of the Domain.

Can anyone help me?  Thanks!

[here is a screen shot of my Group policy management console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV8T0.png)